# If contains the substring, generate a new column with TRUE

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to tag TRUE or FALSE to an email message dataframe that has columns SenderEmail, Counterparties, and MessageBody

```
df['Spam'] = df['SenderEmail'].apply(lambda x: True if "no" and "reply" in x.lower() else "")
df['Spam'] = df['MessageBody'].apply(lambda x: True if "please do not reply" in x.lower() else "")
```

The code works, but I realise that after I ran one after the other, the results from the second line code will overrun the results from the first line code, leaving me with the results from the second line code only. I can’t remove the else “” while using this, so I was thinking to run a for loop instead. But I’m not sure how to do so.

Comment: `"no" and "reply" in x.lower()` does not do what you think.

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and then try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve).
In particular try to provide a simple dataframe and the expected output.

Comment: You should use `df['MessageBody'].str.lower().str.contains("please do not reply")` instead of `apply`.

Comment: Does str.contains() can be used in a for loop, and can match more than 2 words (“no” and “reply”)?

Comment: @StevenLiang `pd.Series.str.contains` can match multiple words by using a regex.  Check the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas-series-str-contains) for an example.

Comment: Don't you actually want to check for `no reply` string? Or do you want to get `True` if the string is `reply followed in no time`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes to the later, as long as there is “no” and “reply”, get True

Comment: @0x5453 ahhh i see, but how do you turn it into a for loop, given that there 2 words to match? For str(df.iloc[1,df.columns.get_loc(“SenderEmail)]).str.contains(“no”|”reply) == “no” and “reply”

Comment: @StevenLiang You don't need to use a loop, all of the `.str` functions are vectorized.  So e.g. `df['Spam'] = (df['SenderEmail'].str.lower().str.contains('no|reply') | df['MessageBody'].str.lower().str.contains('please do not reply'))`

Comment: Is there also a way to include 3 substrings to match with a mix of “and” “or”, so hence it would (“no” and “reply” or”please”)

Comment: @StevenLiang Yes, `'^(?=.*no)(?=.*(?:reply|please))'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['Spam'] = (df['SenderEmail'].str.contains('^(?=.*no)(?=.*reply)', case=False) | 
              df['MessageBody'].str.contains('please do not reply', case=False))
```

Here,

- `df['SenderEmail'].str.contains('^(?=.*no)(?=.*reply)', case=False)` checks if the `SenderEmail` column value contains both substrings `no` and `reply`
- `df['MessageBody'].str.contains('please do not reply', case=False)` checks if `MessageBody` column contains `please do not reply` substring.

The `case=False` enables case insensitive checking.

Pandas test:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'SenderEmail': ['no reply', 'reply', 'no', 'and more no some reply'], 
     'MessageBody':['ok', 'please do not reply', 'ok', 'ok']})
df['Spam'] = (df['SenderEmail'].str.contains('^(?=.*no)(?=.*reply)', case=False) | 
              df['MessageBody'].str.contains('please do not reply', case=False))
# => df
#                 SenderEmail          MessageBody   Spam
#   0                no reply                   ok   True
#   1                   reply  please do not reply   True
#   2                      no                   ok  False
#   3  and more no some reply                   ok   True
```

Comment: This works wonders! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Is there also a way to include 3 substrings to match with a mix of “and” “or”, so hence it would (“no” and “reply” or”please”)

Comment: And also make an exception, whereby if the Subject column has “RE: “, it will always be False even if the other logic says it is True

Comment: @StevenLiang Then you might try `df['Spam'] = (df['SenderEmail'].str.contains(r'^(?=.*no)(?=.*(?:reply|please))', case=False) | df['MessageBody'].str.contains(r'please do not reply', case=False) | df['Subject'].str.contains(r'^(?!.*RE:)'))`